# Passing model to asp-for | ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to create a button which takes Model values, calculates them, them re-passes the model (to not lost info already inputted). I've tried passing the model for asp-for="@Model" but that just fires an error saying that asp-for cannot be null/blank.

Model

```
    {
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string JobDescription { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Postcode From")]
        public string PostcodeFrom { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Postcode To")]
        public string PostcodeTo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Mileage")]
        public int TotalMiles { get; set; }
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

View Model

```
    public class JobDetailViewModel
    {
        public Job Job { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Actions

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var jobDetailViewModel = new JobDetailViewModel();
            jobDetailViewModel.Customers = _context.Customers.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.CustomerId.ToString(), Text = c.CustomerName }).ToList();
            return View(jobDetailViewModel);
        }

and

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult CalculateMilage(JobDetailViewModel model)
        {
            model.Job = new Job();
            model.Job.TotalMiles = 123;
            return View("Create", model);
        }
```

Attempted button call

```
@model DHSCRM.ViewModels.JobDetailViewModel
<form asp-action="CalculateMilage" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model" />
    <button class="btn btn-info" value="Calculate">Calculate Milage</button>
</form>
```

Whenever I hit the button it either passes a blank model, or fails. I've tried to ignore asp-for but again it passes in blank, and I'm not entirely sure why.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

EDIT - Entire view

```
@model DHSCRM.ViewModels.JobDetailViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Job</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Job.JobName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Job.JobName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Job.JobName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Job.JobDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Job.JobDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Job.JobDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Job.PostcodeFrom" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Job.PostcodeFrom" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Job.PostcodeFrom" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Job.PostcodeTo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Job.PostcodeTo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Job.PostcodeTo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Job.TotalMiles" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Job.TotalMiles" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Job.TotalMiles" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerName" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Job.CustomerId" asp-items="@Model.Customers">
                    <option selected></option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Job.CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<form asp-action="CalculateMilage" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model" />
    <button class="btn btn-info" value="Calculate">Calculate Milage</button>
</form>

<hr />
@TempData["ButtonValue"]
<hr />

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole view pls? I don't understand why  you need to pass model to view and after this return it  back to the controller not touched.

Comment: Hi Sergey. I've edited my answer now, I expected to be able to pass the current model (as captured in the rest of the form) when clicking that button. Thinking about it... Do I need the button to be within the rest of the Create form?

Comment: You can't do this the way you want. You have to submit the whole view, calculate and return back. Or you can use ajax to call the controller action and return calculated value as json.  After this using jquery  you can refresh the total mileage.

Comment: Right okay, so there's no way to dynamically update page details without ajax when using a model? So if I wanted Model.Field3 to be Model.Field 1 + Model.Field 2 I'd have to do that in ajax?

Comment: Yes, you are correct or you have to submit the whole form. Or if it simple you can just use jquery and don't send it to the server.

Comment: Can you post what are you need to calculate. It seems to me that you don't need ajax and all callculation can be make on the client site just using jquery.

Comment: Hi Sergery, in an ideal world I click the button and it will run an API. But if we say that PostcodeOne + PostcodeTwo hopefully that will make a start? So I want to add the two values of those two fields together.

Comment: I  posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to calculate the fields of your form. This is just a sample.

At first give ids to your controls:

```
           <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Job.PostcodeFrom"  class="control-label"></label>
              <input asp-for="Job.PostcodeFrom" id="postCodeFrom" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Job.PostcodeFrom" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Job.PostcodeTo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Job.PostcodeTo" id="postCodeTo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Job.PostcodeTo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Job.TotalMiles" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Job.TotalMiles" id="totalMiles" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Job.TotalMiles" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            ....
```

replace

```
<form asp-action="CalculateMilage" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model" />
    <button class="btn btn-info" value="Calculate">Calculate Milage</button>
</form>
```

with

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="btnCalculate"> Calculate Milage</button>
```

and put the script in the script section:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

$(document).on("click", "#btnCalculate", (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

       var  postCodeFrom = $("#postCodeFrom").val();
       var  postCodeTo = $("#postCodeTo").val();
       var total= postCodeFrom+postCodeTo;

         $("#totalMiles").val(total);

    }));

});
```

Comment: Do note that this moves the logic from the server to the client. This may let an attacker change how milage is calculated. This may be unwanted behavior.

Comment: Yes, I agree but if you read the comments  PO  just needs a  very simple example.

Comment: @RichardBarker - Would you have a safer method of doing this? My end goal is to take two postcodes from PostcodeOne and PostcodeTwo then call a method which runs google API and finds the distance, and then updates "TotalMiles" with that example.

Comment: @DanielHill you have to create a new post and if you can wait till tomorrow I can make this code for you when I have some time.  Or somebody else can try it before I start.

Comment: That would be amazing thank you, it's just a personal project so I'm in no rush! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let me know when you create a new post

Comment: Your best bet is to use a bit of Javscript to get the inputs from one form over to the other form - which is why your model is empty when you post it - and then post that with a submit button. This will let you calculate on the server and you can return the model to the view with the calculated output - which I think you can do in the create form instead of a separate form anyway.

Comment: Hi all, I've figured this out using a AJAX query and a specific method within the Controller :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DanielHill It's up to you.  I can always help  when you have a problem. Good luck!